# lowest bin value histogram opencv

Tags: opencv, histogram

Is it possible to get the most left bin value after a peak as in the image.
I had tried the syntax below but it always return of coz the first bin (0,0).

```
cv::Point min_loc, max_loc;
cv::minMaxLoc(g_hist, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc );  
cout<<"\nMax Histo: "<<max;
cout<<"\nmax_loc: "<<max_loc;
```

[image]

l_hist: [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0; 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0; 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;28.571428;400;166.96428;63.392857;0;33.92857;88.392853;18.75;**3.5714285**;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0; 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;  0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]

the bin is 165. I need to get the number of the bin.

Comment: Can you show expected output with some sample data ?

Comment: Iterator in your ghist, then find the non-zero minvalue.

Comment: Hi ZdaR, edited in the comments. My output would be the bin value as eg, 165 which consist the lowest value before it turns to always zero towards 255 bin.